# formatting sqlite3_exec result

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

Hello how would I go about formatting the result of

```
   sql = "SELECT * from COMPANY ORDER BY ID";

   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
```

I read there are console commands for it on here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_commands.htm

so I tried

```
   std::string c3 = "sqlite>.header on";
   std::string c1 = "sqlite>.mode column";

   cout << system(c3.c_str()) << endl;
   cout << system(c1.c_str()) << endl;
```

but that didn't work to get a table format like result

How would I do this? I've been googling for 3 hours and still didn't get anywhere

Comment: `sqlite>.header on` is not a valid shell command. and since each system will start the `sqlite3` in a new shell, it will not work this way. You should not mix `sqlite3` user program commands with C apis, because it will not work. You should receive the results and format them using `printf()` or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the formatting from the `sqlite3` user program, so using `system()` to call it will not control the C API.

You should do this using the `callback` function. From the same [tutorialpoint site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm):

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);

   for(i = 0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }

   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, 

this gives me this result: 
https://i.imgur.com/2pS5niN.png

and not the table format i'd wish to get, did I do something wrong?

wanted result : https://i.imgur.com/IXvVPEu.png